# HTTP Response Code on javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers, http-response-codes

How can I do a HTTPget response code on a bogus link on javascript?

I really have no idea what HTTP response codes are and for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way also

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var url = "/customers/customer_list";
  $.ajax({url:url,
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html"
    success:function(result){
      alert(result);
    }});
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Use javascript to check http status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571227/use-javascript-to-check-http-status-codes)

```
$(function() {
  var url = "some_url";
  $.ajax(url,
  {
     statusCode: {
     404: function() {
        alert('page not found');
     }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
});
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
For detailed info on what these mean

Comment: Just realised you mean a get request, updating answer now

Comment: No, don't edit your answer. It is what I'm looking for. Just a follow up questions.

How do I test if that function? and how I locate (header/body) and call (onclick/.ready) that function?

Comment: replace 'url' with the address of your server. Inside the `404: function() { <your code here>` you can fire any handlers you want. For more info on getting the status code / body see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/