# how to redirect a webpage with the "http error 404" to the default webpage automatically?

Tags: javascript

In case the user entry to an "unavailable site" within a website, the "http error 404" happen!!!, how to redirect a webpage with the "http error 404" to the default webpage automatically?

Is it possible?, when the HTTP status is 404, the webpage redirect itself automatically to the default page without click any button.

Comment: I read from some post, it is about to use ".htaccess" file to redirect the url. but where should I put this file in? which folder?

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP status if it is `404` then redirect to your default page.

[How to check HTTP status code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571227/use-javascript-to-check-http-status-codes)

Redirect to your default webpage using:

```
    window.location = "your-default-webpage.html";
```

Comment: how to redirect to the default page?

Comment: Is it possible?, when the HTTP status is 404 the webpage redirect itself automatically to the default page without click any button.

Comment: @charnstyle Yes. I suggest you to read up on basics of HTML and Javascript. Then it will be easy to do this task. What I have mentioned in the answer are the keys to achieve what you want.

Comment: @RahulDesai, how is someone supposed to use `window.location`, a JavaScript property, on a page which doesn't exist? By definition you can't run JavaScript if you don't have a page. This will have to be handled by something server-side to redirect the user.