# JavaScript visibilitchange Event not fire on mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile

Is it possible to know when Chrome loads a page from cache?
There is a strange behavior when you start Chrome on Android: Chrome starts to load the page, but not from server, and there is no event fired in JavaScript for that loading.

Answer (score 0):

**200** *(OK)* is the code for resouces correctly loaded from server
**304** *(Not Modified)* is the code for resources that have not changed and therefore is not necesary to retransmit

If you want to track a resource in specific you could send an ajax request for the resource and check the response status

Here is how to
[Ajax statusCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571227/use-javascript-to-check-http-status-codes)