# HTTP Status Code from URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, playframework, http-status-codes

I'm trying to find a function that return HTTP Status Code from an URL, and then "make something" based on the returned statuses (404, 416, 200 etc...)

Can someone help me? I've tried the other functions posted here on StackOverflow but anyone was usefull for my purpose.

I need to integrate this function inside my PlayFramework web-app.

Thanks a lot

Comment: if using jquery, this is the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8571617/724913

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following ..?

```
function getStatus(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4){
            request.status;//this contains the status code
        }
    };
request.open("GET", url , true);
request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Have this function a return?

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/fLzujvdx/) is the implementation of the above function