# Catch script tags 404

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to catch `<script type="text/javascript" src="..">` 404 with JavaScript so that I could correct `src`?

`window.onerror` doesn't seem to catch these.

Important note! This script is dynamically added into body by 3rd-party library, so I have no control over it.

---

It would be so nice if I could detect the script insertion or `src` setting and update it with correct `src` like I could do with image but I think it's not possible with script element?

```js
  var NativeImage = window.Image;

  class MyImage {
    constructor (w, h) {
      var nativeImage = new NativeImage(w, h);

      var handler = {
        set: function (obj, prop, value) {
          if (prop === 'src') {
            return nativeImage[prop] = '/correct/image/path.jpg';
          }
          return nativeImage[prop] = value;
        },
        get: function (target, prop) {
          return target[prop];
        }
      };

      return new Proxy(nativeImage, handler);
    }
  }

  window.Image = MyImage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect the script's insertion with MutationObserver and add an `error` listener to the tag:

```js
// Your code (run this before the external script)
new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutations) {
    for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
      // Add additional checks here if needed
      // to identify if the script is the one added by the library
      if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.matches('script')) {
        node.addEventListener('error', () => {
          console.log('Script could not be loaded');
        });
        // Remove the observer, since its purpose is fulfilled
        observer.disconnect();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
})
  // Watch for elements that are added as children to document.body:
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true });
```

```html
<script>
// External script:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'doesntexist';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the HTTP Status of your script src by sending a XMLHttpRequest:
[HTTP Status Code from URL in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097819/http-status-code-from-url-in-javascript)

```
function getStatus(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4){
       return request.status;
};
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send(); 
}
```