# Error 404 on img src can't replace image - vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, json, image, replace, fetch

Since few days i am stuggling with some problem on img replace in javascript.
I am coding this application with course, but in this course video img replacing work well. probably main cause is that I fetch other API. Its opportunity for me to learn how to solve this kind of problems but i can't find answer since few days.

Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/sowicz/pen/xxjyXVO

And problem is in this lines below.
Because of some serials data from json can't be load (GET 404 error) I want to replace img for some img from pixabay.
Unfortunately it doesn't work. I can't solve this issue.

```
if(serials.Poster) {
                imgSrc = serials.Poster;
            } else {
                this.imgSrc = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg"
            }
```

I am very sorry if something is missing, I am new in coding.
Thanks a lot in advance, and wish you good day!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You attempt to use the fallback image, if your API's data does not provide an image URL. Please note that as an image URL is provided (albeit it points to a location that does not exists) your else-Block ist not executed in this case.
This is because

```
if ( serials.Poster )
```

just checks, that the attribute Poster is present in the object "serials".
It completely ignores whether this contains a valid URL or even points to an existing location.

If you want to check in vanilla JS whether that image can be loaded from it's URL, I suggest you do an XHR and check the status for the 20X-range. See [HTTP Status Code from URL in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097819/http-status-code-from-url-in-javascript) for more detail.

I suggest you try that in isolation, so you can better narrow the issue down. You can use

```
let serials = {
    "Poster": "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"
}

if ( serials.Poster ) { // TODO: improve this
    imgSrc = serials.Poster;
} else {
    imgSrc = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg";
}  

console.log("imgSrc:", imgSrc);
```

and try out what happens if you misspelled Poster to understand what I mean.

EDIT / APPENDING:

As nyx's answer already pointed out the probably simplest way to achieve this is by adding an onerror-Handler to the affected image tag.

```
getShowBoxByTemplate: function(imgSrc, title, date, overview){
return `
    <div class="show-box">
        <img src="${imgSrc}" alt="Movie Poster for ${title}" onerror="this.src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg'">
        <div class="show-tittle">${title}</div>
        <div class="Date">${date}</div>
        <div class="show-overview">${overview}</div>
    </div> 
`
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir so much! I have tired 3 days but can't find solution.
Already checked the status of URL and confirm but I can't use if statement to provide url from server or from other source. 
The if statement always has done before XHR have results. I have to stop then i learn a bit more about async.

Comment: I think the solution originally proposed by nhy's answer is way more elegant than my initial suggestion to check the resource via XHR. So I suggest you make your life easier by adopting the onerror-Handler to set the intended fallback image.
Please consider marking nhx's answer as the accepted answer, so others will find the elegant and working solution quicker.

Answer (score 2):

`this.imgSrc =`  is same as `showsApp.imgSrc`.
the problem is you use `imgSrc` as local var to call method `getShowBoxByTemplate`.

I think we should change it into

```js
let imgSrc = null;

if (serials.Poster) {
    imgSrc = serials.Poster;
} else {
    imgSrc = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg"
}
```

or

```js
const imgSrc = !!serials.Poster ? serials.Poster : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg"
```

or

```js
const imgSrc = serials.Poster || "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg"
```

if your image responds with 404 code you can use `onerror` event like the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

```html
<img src="${imgSrc}" onerror="this.src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg'" alt="">
```

Comment: Many thanks for answer!
The same results, img from pixabay don't load.
Console shows: GET 404 error

Comment: i did edit answer with the part to handle image response with code 404.
you can use `<img src="${imgSrc}" onerror="this.src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/31/11/28/snakes-head-fritillary-7102810__340.jpg'" alt="">
` for the `<image>` in method `getShowBoxByTemplate`

Comment: Thank a lot! now it works!
I still got errors in console 'GET 'link' 404' error - so i need to try solutrion from Sascha Scherrer.
Thank you guys!

Comment: This should be the correct solution. The API returns a value for `serials.Poster` meaning the `if` statement always sets `imgSrc` to `serials.Poster`. The 404 message means the image URL the API returned is not found on the server, which is the API/server's fault. Using `onerror` is how you should handle missing/invalid image URLs.