# Is there a way to make "target='_blank'" only for the redirected links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring mvc project where there is one scenario that on click of a button view is displayed in the same tab. but in certain scenario it is redirected to another url.
             so at this time when there is redirect i want to open in new tab.

**conclusion** : *I want to know whether there is any way to open in new tab if there is url redirection otherwise open in the same tab*.

Comment: What do you mean by "URL redirection" ? Also, as a side remark, you shouldn't choose for your users and let them decide if they want the link to open in a new tab/window or not.

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571227/use-javascript-to-check-http-status-codes) to check the response code. After that decide whether to open a new window or not.

Comment: @Bartdude my question is simple, i just want to know if there is redirect in code, it should be displayed in new tab.

Comment: Yeah your question is simple when you don't know much but I can probably think about 5 or 6 ways to do a redirection, was it from server or client-side. So that's not THAT simple. Which kind of redirection are we talking about here ?

Comment: @Bartdude server side.

Comment: Then remark from LSA points you to the correct direction : catch the click event on anchor, perform a request to the URL, get status code and act accordingly whther this is a redirection or not...

Answer (score 0):

This will alter all your links, adding target="_blank" to them if they do not share your domain, if that is what you mean:

```
var slice = location.href.split('/');
var domain = slice[1] ? slice[0] : slice[2];
$('a').each(function()
{
    if (this.href.indexOf(domain) < 0)
    {
        $(this).attr('target','_blank');
    }
});
```