# How to make login authentication page in HTML or JAVASCRIPT

Tags: authentication, html

I am from electronics background so don't have good knowledge in designing webpages. I am doing an ethernet project and for that I need to make a webpage but before that webpage I also need to make a login authentication webpage. I somehow managed to do it using HTML JAVASCRIPT but the problem is anyone can see the username password by viewing the page source.

I am having hard time making authentication. I have basic knowledge of HTML and JAVASCRIPT but ready to learn. All I can find on google is login templates but I don't even know how to use them.

Can anyone give me an example or point me to some good links.

Answer (score 10):

HTML and Javascript are interpreted on the [client side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting). For login purposes, it is the server side code that is commonly used to verify the credentials - simply because that fact that you are already aware of - with a simple client side implementation, you can see the credentials in source code, server side is also easier to work with, once you understand it, it is more flexible for further development, it is more secure, and it is really used everywhere for this task.

It is a good idea to use PHP, ASP, Ruby (or any other [server side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Languages) language) for this. If you do not want that, you need to make it hard for the user to read the credentials from the source code.

In order to do that, you can use various methods like cryptography or [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29). Cryptography is highly recommended over obfuscating as it provably adds more security to your application. Obfuscating basically means that you change the source code in a way that it is hard to read - you add functions that encode strings, so that your "password" can not be spotted on the first sight. However, obfuscation can always be bypassed, and usually quite easily with a good debugging tools.

So, let's go with cryptography. What you are looking for here is using [one way hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). You have plenty to choose from - MD5, SHA1, SHA256, ... each provides different level of security. [SHA256 implementation in Javascript](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html) is an example you can use. There are many other libraries and examples for this, so just use Google and find the one that you like.

Now, what to do with it? Say you have sha256() function that accepts a string and returns its hash as a string. For each user and password you have, you precount SHA256 hash of string "user + password".

Say, you want your username to be "Pedro" and password for this account is "MyPassword".

You precount the hash of "PedroMyPassword" - e.g. with [with online hashing tool](http://hash-functions.online-domain-tools.com/run/?inputType=frm-text&text=PedroMyPassword&functions%5B%5D=sha256&do=form-submit). You can see the its SHA256 hash is

```
40be6e939eedf018b2b846e027067dcb006585a2155ce324f1f2a6a71d418b21
```

This hash is what you put into your Javascript code.

When the user enters their user and password, you call your sha256 function on "username + password" and you compare it to your precounted hash.

Note that you have to select really strong password, otherwise certain attacks (such as dictionary attack) would be easy to use to break your hash.

The problem is now, that you did not specify, what you want to do next. For example, you might want to redirect authenticated users to next page, but here you have the same problem again - if you have redirection in Javascript to "secondpage.html" in your code, someone could just skip the authentication and navigate to this second page directly.

What you can do in this case is that you name your second page as

```
40be6e939eedf018b2b846e027067dcb006585a2155ce324f1f2a6a71d418b21.html
```

i.e. the hash of your user+pass string. In this variant you do not put the hash in the code at all. The web server will just return error 404 for all users that fail to authenticate. For example, if someone attempts to use "Pedro" with "123456" as password, the SHA256 would be

3bac31720fdd4619ebe2e8865ccc0dc87eb744f3f05f08c628bb9217a77e4517

and if you redirect them to

3bac31720fdd4619ebe2e8865ccc0dc87eb744f3f05f08c628bb9217a77e4517.html

it won't exist, because your second page file is called

```
40be6e939eedf018b2b846e027067dcb006585a2155ce324f1f2a6a71d418b21.html
```

You would need to create these second pages for each user/pass combination. You could then put a simple redirection code to the real second page.

But make sure you are using HTTPS protocol, otherwise, the second pages would go through the wire unencrypted ...

This all will work, but still, I highly suggest, you consider the server side way.

Comment: Thanks for this good information. This is what I want. Can you please explain the server side way also or point me to some useful links.?

Comment: Server side is what is used everywhere. Once you understand it, it is easier, more secure, much more flexible for future development and is just the thing to use. For server side, it depends on what technology can you use on your server. If you host it yourself, you can choose among all different technologies (ASP, PHP, Ruby, NodeJs, ...). But if you are on third party hosting, you are usually limited. The lowest cost hostings usually run on Linux OS and offer PHP. There are plenty of resource on the Internet for this - e.g. http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html is a simple PHP+MySQL sample.

Comment: If you do not want to use database, it is OK, you can simply modify that sample to cut DB code off. There are also many SO questions here on that topic, so make your search for "simple PHP login form". Or you can try this one http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_login_example.htm , really many many options here. You just need to identify the server side technology you can and want to use and then learn its basics.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually I am using Microcontroller which will be hosting all the webpages. So I don't know what technology to use here. But I'll try to do it this way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with microcontrollers, but if you run any unix/linux on that, you might be able to run anything and you will just be limited by HW resources (e.g. available memory). Having said that, things like PHP have plenty of settings you can tweak, memory limits included.

Answer (score 3):

In my previous answer I was using client side technologies thats why the username and password was not safe and hidden if we check the page-source.

Now,we will use server side technology, for this you need web-server package such as WAMP,XAMPP etc

Download and install one of these packages.(if you have one of these two, then its well and good)

I am using XAMPP so I will explain with XAMPP.

If you have successfully downloaded XAMPP,
then look for the *htdocs* folder in XAMPP folder. Mine is "C:\xampp\htdocs"

copy the below code and create new php fileand  Save this file as login.php in *htdocs* directory.

Here is php code.

```html
<?php
 $usr="root";
 $pwd="root";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ){

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

 
   if(($username==$usr) && ($password==$pwd) ){

        echo '<br>login successfull';

    }else{

       echo '<br>login unsuccessfull';
       }
 }else{
   echo "<br>Connot be left empty!";
   }
?>
```

ok!! Now Create a simple **HTML** page containing login form and save this as login.html

Here is the HTML code

```html
<html>
<head>

<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="login.php" method="POST" align="center">
<br>
Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br><br><br>
Password :<input type="text" name="password"><br><br>

<input type="Submit"  value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, Goto browser->Type http://localhost/login.html and run 
Insert Username and password as **root**.

I am assuming you have basic knowledge of php, if not go through it, its is very easy and also read about HTTP requests

- GET
- POST

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
<head>

<title>Login paget</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(form){
if (form.username.value=="root") { 
  if (form.password.value=="root") {              
          location="page2.html" 
           } else {
             alert("Invalid Password")
             }
        } else {  alert("Invalid Username")
          }
      }
   </script>   
<body >

<form >
<input type="text" name="username" /><br><br>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Login" onClick="display(this.form)"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello I have created a login page for you using html and Javascript. The Username and password are **root**.
You see if you input correct username and password then the page directs to page2.html and this will show you

> This webpage is not found

ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

so what you have to do is replace page2.html with your next page name.

Comment: I think you didnt get my question. If someone view the page source, he can easily check what username and password is.? I dont want this king of page

Comment: ohh yes!! you can separate out that javascript code and create a separate file.js  and can reference that js file in ur html code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really have a secure authentication system using JavaScript and HTML alone.

I would suggest [Basic HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on your server instead, as it is much more secure (not perfect by any means, but at least employs a  standard server-side method of access control).

If you must implement something in JavaScript, you could do a password only scheme based on the name of a hidden directory. Something like the following (note this is untested so will need some tweaks):

(Code borrowed and adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571617/413180))

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
      var url = "some_url";
      $.ajax(url,
      {
         if (statusCode == 200) {
           document.location.href = url;
         }
         else {
           alert('Incorrect password')
         }
      }
   });   
});
</script>

<input type="password" /><a href="javascript:void(0)">Login</a>
```

The code should be finished so that the function is called when the button is clicked. So if the password is foo, you set a directory on your website called `foo`, and if the JQuery JavaScript detects that the entered password matches a directory name (e.g. `/foo/`), then the user is redirected there. Therefore you'd create a `/foo/index.html` in order to take care of the user's logged in session.

Note that this is the most secure thing you can do with JavaScript and HTML alone and it suffers from the following vulnerabilities.

- It requires that the URL be kept secret, although this can be leaked by the referer header, by browser history and server/proxy logs.
- Once a user is logged in, they are always logged in (they could bookmark the logged in pages)
- There is no easy way to revoke a password.
- There is only one password.
- Anyone with access to view files on the server could view the directory structure and learn the password.
- The URL may be leaked by analytics tools.
- Assumes directory browsing on your server is disabled (or that there's a default page in the private page's parent directory).

In any case, always protect your server with TLS/SSL. My recommendation is to properly create a user authentication system using the advice from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet). The above shows only what's achievable in basic HTML (not much). However, it is better than exposing the password within client-side files.

Answer (score -3):

just try out this code
 -

```js
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if ( username == "username1" && password == "password1"){
alert ("Login successfully");
  }
  else{
    alert("Invalid username or password");
    }
  return false;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Login Form Validation</title>
<!-- Include JS File Here -->
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
<label>User Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide proper problem description

Comment: I think you didnt get my question. If someone view the page source, he can easily check what username and password is.? I dont want this king of page

Comment: Just place the java script in a new javascript file named as login.js and then when ever the vaidate function is called the values are sent to the java script.  then the java script file is not displayed in the source code

Comment: I wanted it to be simple and your method works great for me.!

Comment: @user007: Then a user just views the source of the JavaScript file to get the password.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Oh no I just realized user can also view js file. My bad. I am really a beginner in this.